# How to sort the output based on increasing order of file naming

Tags: r

I have to read bunch of files based on pattern , but the issue comes up when the file hits double digit labeling.

```
bamsToCount1
 [1] "MACS2_peak_call/filtered_peaks/cons//Blast1.bed"  "MACS2_peak_call/filtered_peaks/cons//Blast10.bed"
 [3] "MACS2_peak_call/filtered_peaks/cons//Blast11.bed" "MACS2_peak_call/filtered_peaks/cons//Blast12.bed"
 [5] "MACS2_peak_call/filtered_peaks/cons//Blast13.bed" "MACS2_peak_call/filtered_peaks/cons//Blast14.bed"
 [7] "MACS2_peak_call/filtered_peaks/cons//Blast15.bed" "MACS2_peak_call/filtered_peaks/cons//Blast16.bed"
 [9] "MACS2_peak_call/filtered_peaks/cons//Blast17.bed" "MACS2_peak_call/filtered_peaks/cons//Blast18.bed"
[11] "MACS2_peak_call/filtered_peaks/cons//Blast19.bed" "MACS2_peak_call/filtered_peaks/cons//Blast2.bed" 
[13] "MACS2_peak_call/filtered_peaks/cons//Blast20.bed" "MACS2_peak_call/filtered_peaks/cons//Blast21.bed"
[15] "MACS2_peak_call/filtered_peaks/cons//Blast22.bed" "MACS2_peak_call/filtered_peaks/cons//Blast23.bed"
[17] "MACS2_peak_call/filtered_peaks/cons//Blast3.bed"  "MACS2_peak_call/filtered_peaks/cons//Blast4.bed" 
[19] "MACS2_peak_call/filtered_peaks/cons//Blast5.bed"  "MACS2_peak_call/filtered_peaks/cons//Blast6.bed" 
[21] "MACS2_peak_call/filtered_peaks/cons//Blast7.bed"  "MACS2_peak_call/filtered_peaks/cons//Blast8.bed" 
[23] "MACS2_peak_call/filtered_peaks/cons//Blast9.bed"  "MACS2_peak_call/filtered_peaks/cons//LSC1.bed"   
[25] "MACS2_peak_call/filtered_peaks/cons//LSC2.bed"    "MACS2_peak_call/filtered_peaks/cons//LSC3.bed"   
[27] "MACS2_peak_call/filtered_peaks/cons//LSC4.bed"    "MACS2_peak_call/filtered_peaks/cons//LSC5.bed"   
[29] "MACS2_peak_call/filtered_peaks/cons//LSC6.bed"    "MACS2_peak_call/filtered_peaks/cons//LSC7.bed"   
[31] "MACS2_peak_call/filtered_peaks/cons//LSC8.bed"
```

The output i m expecting is after `Blast1`, there should be `Blast2`. Right now I see `Blast10` is the second element

Any suggestion or help would be really appreciated

Comment: `gtools::mixedsort(bamsToCount1)`

Comment: That was pretty fast .thank u